# C - How to define a global variable using a loop?

Tags: c, arrays

Sorry if this is a simple question, but I've searched this a lot and found nothing relevant, probably because I'm new to programming and don't know the specific jargons. 
So, I've a program that works fine. In the beginning of the code, I define the following array as a global variable:

```
static double arr[] = {
    [0] = 50,
    [1] = 0
};
```

However, I'm dealing with a huge amount of data my array need to have a lot of elements. If i was allowed to use a loop inside the definition of my variable, It would be very easy. However, everytime I try this i get the following error message

```
expected primary-expression before
```

What can I do in order to properly define the elements of my array?

Comment: Use a container, as explained in any better C++ tutorial. Also, make sure you understand the three different meanings that `static` can take!

Comment: You could write a program to code generate large datasets and just include those files.

Comment: So which language do you use now? C like in the title or C++ like in the tags?

Comment: Note that this question once stipulated C++, but now stipulates C.  Please be careful, everyone who answers.  Don't shoot those who answered while the question was tagged C++ and contained C++ in the title.

Comment: Ulrich, some people said to me that my code wasn't valid in C++. As I said before, I'm a complete noob, so I decided to play safe and change the title and the tags. Bug I'm pretty sure I'm using C++, as I'm learning things reading an C++ book.

Comment: Which C++ book are you reading that has this notation in it, @StephenDedalus?  We want to know so we can spot the problem in future.  And please can you identify which compiler you're using, and the command line you used, and the platform you're working on?  These could be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For C style array, you would need to declare the variable before hand with the necessary size.

```cpp
static double arr[YOUR_SIZE];
```

Then only in main, you can populate the elements

```
int main () {
    for (int i=0; i < ((sizeof(arr))/(sizeof(arr[0])))); ++i) {
        //whatever here
        arr[i] = i;
    }
}
```

For C++, you could use runtime allocated vectors

```
std::vector<double> arr;

int main () {
    for (int i=0; i < YOUR_MAX; ++i) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems ok to me, but it doesn't work in my code.

Comment: @Jack maybe he speaks with a Lisp

Comment: `arr[i] = [i];` should be `arr[i] = i;`

Comment: @MattMcNabb I realized that, but its the same. The program doesn't run properly.

Comment: @StephenDedalus, to use vector, you need to add the include line `#include <vector>`

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use designated initializers in C99 and later, the standard requires the initializers to be written out long-hand.  GCC provides a range-initialization extension so that you can initialize a range of indexes with the same non-zero value (you don't need the extension to initialize everything to zeros).

```
int array[100] =
{
    [50 ... 80] = 27,  // GCC extension
};
```

Note that the spaces are needed around the ellipsis because of the 'maximimal munch' rule.  `50.` looks like a valid floating point number, which is not, therefore a valid array index.

However, even in GCC, you can't have a loop written out in an initializer.

Comment: Kind of over the OP's head?